# Different behavior of Bootstrap in different browsers

Tags: iframe, twitter-bootstrap

check the following link in different browsers:
http://www.northeastern.edu/sds/web/demos/demos_climate_prec_001.shtml

click the first option (top left) in the left table.(it opens an iframe)

- in Chrome a row of thumbnail appears in the bottom (It is what it is expected) and you can click on them to see the original size
- but in firefox and IE it shows different behavior and the photoes are shown in their original sizes.

How can I solve this problem?
Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I can definitely see your problem.  I tried with IE 8 and 9 - both show the full sized images rather than the thumbnails, unlike Chrome.

One solution would be to add a class to your `img` tags and size the images there.  When I tried with IE 8 and 9, this appeared to do the trick.

CSS (place either in a file after your bootstrap.css in your header or declare in your head using a `script` tag):

```
.myThumbnail {
    width:224px;
    height:147px;
}
```

Then modify your HTML such that each of your `img` tags have the `myThumbnail` class.

I know this is not the ideal solution, but it works.